# Availability Checks Break Preview Macro with Nested Type Declaration

Tags: swift, swiftui, macros, preview

If you wish to use `State` properties with the new `Preview` macro, you'll have to create a wrapper for it:

```swift
#Preview(body: {
    Preview()
})

private struct Preview: View {
    @State private var isOn: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        Toggle(
            isOn: $isOn,
            label: EmptyView.init
        )
        .labelsHidden()
    }
}
```

Not only does this clutter the codebase, but it forces you to use arbitrary names, in case of multiple previews per file.

That's why, type declaration can be nested directly within the macro:

```swift
#Preview(body: {
    struct Preview: View {
        @State private var isOn: Bool = true

        var body: some View {
            Toggle(
                isOn: $isOn,
                label: EmptyView.init
            )
            .labelsHidden()
        }
    }

    return Preview()
})
```

However, the macro has a problem compiling, when we attach availability attributes to it—

```swift
@available(iOS 17.0, *)
#Preview(body: {
    struct Preview: View {
        @State private var isOn: Bool = true

        var body: some View {
            Toggle(
                isOn: $isOn,
                label: EmptyView.init
            )
            .labelsHidden()
        }
    }

    return Preview()
})
```

—which is strange, since simple previews with availability checks compile just fine:

```swift
@available(iOS 17.0, *)
#Preview(body: {
    Text("Hello World")
})
```

The compiler throws the following error:

> Compiling failed: 'Preview' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer.

Are there any alternatives out there, instead of relying on an external type declaration shown in the first snippet?

Comment: I am on 15.2. Pasting the third snippet in the project does it for me. Just to clarify, project compiles fine, but preview doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found is to check `#available` *inside* the preview closure:

```
#Preview {
    guard #available(iOS 17.0, *) else { return EmptyView() }
    struct Preview: View {
        @State private var isOn: Bool = true
        
        var body: some View {
            ...
        }
    }
    return Preview()
}
```

Comment: Although it does work, it still leaves empty simulator for preview. Plus, it's not a global solution since not all projects may run on iOS 15 or 17 to use different #Preview macros. So that's why I was doing that in the first place. Seems like a bug to me, since macro expansion probably attaches availability attributes incorrectly to the nested type declarations

Comment: @Vakho What you are saying doesn't make sense. "It still leaves empty simulator for preview" contradicts "it does work". And I cannot reproduce that. Is the preview device not iOS 17? If it isn't, then it is natural for the preview to not show anything. If it is iOS 17, then I cannot reproduce that. And I didn't understand what you mean by "not a global solution". What are "different" `#Preview` macros? This works for all the `#Preview` macro overloads. How is iOS 15 relevant? If the device is iOS 15, it cannot display a preview that needs iOS 17.

Comment: @Vakho I think the bug is worse than that. In theory, you don't need to add `@available` to previews at all. The macro expansion adds a `@available(iOS 17, ...)` to the enclosing `PreviewRegistry` struct. Presumably the version is whatever the latest supported version is. However, when building previews, Xcode doesn't see that `@available`, hence not allowing you to use newer APIs if the minimum deployment is a lower version.